# FTP works from CommandLine but not from Windows Explorer

Tags: ftp

I'm trying to connect from one server to another using FTP. By using command line, everything thing is ok. however when using Windows Explorer to browse to the FTP location i get timeout issue.

I've tried connecting using a .net code, and I got the following exception

The remote server returned an error: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,231,1,4,218).

Comment: Not programming related. It's software related (Windows Explorer). Belongs on superuser.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to connect using an active connection rather than a passive one.  There's a Microsoft Knowledge Base about configuring Internet Explorer at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323446.  The command line ftp.exe doesn't support passive transfers, so to make IE match it you would leave "Use Passive FTP" unchecked.  For any library you use, look for documentation discussing whether it uses `PASV` (passive) or `PORT` (active) to open the data channel.

Answer (score 7):

The question was about Windows Explorer, not IE.  If ftp.exe can connect, but Windows Explorer can't, then you have a Passive FTP server, and you need to *un*-check

**Control Panel > Internet Options > Advanced Settings >** "Use Passive FTP"

then click Apply - now Windows Explorer will be able to connect to the FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, but not the same reason (not passive mode).
Shortly: if you happen to have a '@' in your login, replace it with %40, when creating a new network location in Windows Explorer. Otherwise the system will not find the server or show empty ftp folder. 
Hope it helps someone.